# About while loops and if statements nested

Tags: java

I'm working on this project challenge called "Algebra Tutor" for my very first java class.

> The program should be able to output a question to decide whether you want to solver for `m` or `b` or y in the formula `y = mx + b`.
>
> Once one of those is pick by a number: "Select 1 to Solve for `Y`, `2` to Solve for `M`, `3` to Solve for B and 4 to quit. "
>
> It should give you an output to solve the formula.

I'm working in part 3 of the project which is:

> Update your program so that each problem type mode will repeatedly ask questions until the user gets 3 correct answers in a row.
>
> If the attempts more than 3 questions in a particular mode, the program should provide a hint on how to solve problems of this type.
>
> After the student has correctly answered 3 questions in a row, an overall score (the number of questions answered correctly divided by the total number of questions attempted) should be displayed, and the menu is presented again.

**So I'm getting stuck on how I can place a counter that starts at 0 and every time the user answers correctly then 1 will be added to the counter and quit if it gets 3 in a row or go back to 0 if the user answer is incorrect.**

I will provide my code I'm getting confused on how having a while loop inside of the if statement and then another while loop for the count, it's confusing I know but once you see my code you will see what I'm talking about.

So I know I can place a counter like this:

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 4) 
      if statement here 
       counter ++; 
      else 
        counter = 0;
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class AlgebraTutor {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        double min_value = -100;
        double max_value = 100;

        double m_value = generate_random(max_value, min_value);
        double x_value = generate_random(max_value, min_value);
        double b_value = generate_random(max_value, min_value);
        double y_value = generate_random(max_value, min_value);
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int user_answer_int = 0;

        while ((user_answer_int < 4) && (user_answer_int >= 0)) {
            System.out.println("Select 1 to Solve for Y, 2 to Solve for M, 3 to Solve for B and 4 to quit. ");
            user_answer_int = user_input.nextInt();
            if (user_answer_int == 1) {
                check_answer_for_y(m_value, x_value, b_value);
            }
            else if (user_answer_int == 2) {
                check_answer_for_m(x_value, y_value, b_value);
            }
            else if (user_answer_int == 3) {
                check_answer_for_b(m_value, x_value, y_value);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You are done");
            }

        }
    }

    static void check_answer_for_m(double x_value, double y_value, double b_value) {
        System.out.println("Solve For M Problem ");
        System.out.println("Given: ");
        System.out.println("b = " + b_value);
        System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
        System.out.println("y = " + y_value);

        System.out.print("What is the value of m? ");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_answer_m = "";
        user_answer_m = user_input.next();
        int user_answer_int = Integer.parseInt(user_answer_m);

        int correct_answer_m = (((int)y_value - (int)b_value) / (int)x_value);

        if (user_answer_int == correct_answer_m){
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sorry, that is incorrect. ");
            System.out.println("The answer is " + correct_answer_m);

        }

    }
    static void check_answer_for_b(double m_value, double x_value, double y_value) {
        System.out.println("Solve For B Problem ");
        System.out.println("Given: ");
        System.out.println("m = " + m_value);
        System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
        System.out.println("y = " + y_value);

        System.out.print("What is the value of b? ");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_answer_b = "";
        user_answer_b = user_input.next();
        int user_answer_int = Integer.parseInt(user_answer_b);

        int correct_answer_b = ((int)y_value - ((int)m_value * (int)x_value));

        if (user_answer_int == correct_answer_b){
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sorry, that is incorrect. ");
            System.out.println("The answer is " + correct_answer_b);

        }
    }

    static void check_answer_for_y(double m_value, double x_value, double b_value) {
        System.out.println("Solve For Y Problem ");
        System.out.println("Given: ");
        System.out.println("m = " + m_value);
        System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
        System.out.println("b = " + b_value);

        System.out.print("What is the value of y? ");

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_answer_y = "";
        user_answer_y = user_input.next();
        int user_answer_int = Integer.parseInt(user_answer_y);

        int correct_answer_y = (int) m_value * (int) x_value + (int) b_value;

        if (user_answer_int == correct_answer_y) {
            System.out.println("You are correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sorry, that is incorrect. ");
            System.out.println("The answer is " + correct_answer_y);

        }
    }
    static int generate_random(double max_value, double min_value) {

        return (int) ((int) (Math.random() * ((max_value - min_value)+ 1)) + min_value);
    }
}
```

Where I stated my while loop for the number entered by user 
depending on the number then the if statement jumps in 
where can I place my counter to start and catch all the if statements depending on the number the user picks and then if the user gets 3 correct in a row the program should go back to the main question. Can I do another while loop inside the one I already have? Or should I place it inside each if statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Place the loop here for each

```
else if (user_answer_int == 3) {
        check_answer_for_b(m_value, x_value, y_value);
    }
```

changing your main function to this.

```
     public static void main(String[] arg) {

    double min_value = -100;
    double max_value = 100;

    double m_value = generate_random(max_value, min_value);
    double x_value = generate_random(max_value, min_value);
    double b_value = generate_random(max_value, min_value);
    double y_value = generate_random(max_value, min_value);
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int user_answer_int = 0;

    while ((user_answer_int < 4) && (user_answer_int >= 0)) {
      System.out.println("Select 1 to Solve for Y, 2 to Solve for M, 3 to Solve for B and 4 to quit. ");
      user_answer_int = user_input.nextInt();
      int i = 0;
      if (user_answer_int == 1) {
        while (i < 3){
          if (check_answer_for_y(generate_random(max_value, min_value), generate_random(max_value, min_value), generate_random(max_value, min_value))) {
            i++;
          }
          else {
            i = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      else if (user_answer_int == 2) {
        while (i < 3){
          if (check_answer_for_m(generate_random(max_value, min_value), generate_random(max_value, min_value), generate_random(max_value, min_value))) {
            i++;
          }
          else {
            i = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      else if (user_answer_int == 3) {
        while (i < 3){
          if (check_answer_for_b(generate_random(max_value, min_value), generate_random(max_value, min_value), generate_random(max_value, min_value))) {
            i++;
          }
          else {
            i = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("You are done");
      }
    }
  }
  static boolean check_answer_for_m(double x_value, double y_value, double b_value) {
    System.out.println("Solve For M Problem ");
    System.out.println("Given: ");
    System.out.println("b = " + b_value);
    System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
    System.out.println("y = " + y_value);

    System.out.print("What is the value of m? ");
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user_answer_m = "";
    user_answer_m = user_input.next();
    int user_answer_int = Integer.parseInt(user_answer_m);

    int correct_answer_m = (((int)y_value - (int)b_value) / (int)x_value);

    if (user_answer_int == correct_answer_m){
      System.out.println("You are correct!");
      return true;
    } else {
      System.out.print("Sorry, that is incorrect. ");
      System.out.println("The answer is " + correct_answer_m);
      return false;

    }

  }
  static boolean check_answer_for_b(double m_value, double x_value, double y_value) {
    System.out.println("Solve For B Problem ");
    System.out.println("Given: ");
    System.out.println("m = " + m_value);
    System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
    System.out.println("y = " + y_value);

    System.out.print("What is the value of b? ");
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user_answer_b = "";
    user_answer_b = user_input.next();
    int user_answer_int = Integer.parseInt(user_answer_b);

    int correct_answer_b = ((int)y_value - ((int)m_value * (int)x_value));

    if (user_answer_int == correct_answer_b){
      System.out.println("You are correct!");
      return true;
    } else {
      System.out.print("Sorry, that is incorrect. ");
      System.out.println("The answer is " + correct_answer_b);
      return false;
    }
  }

  static boolean check_answer_for_y(double m_value, double x_value, double b_value) {
    System.out.println("Solve For Y Problem ");
    System.out.println("Given: ");
    System.out.println("m = " + m_value);
    System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
    System.out.println("b = " + b_value);

    System.out.print("What is the value of y? ");

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String user_answer_y = "";
    user_answer_y = user_input.next();
    int user_answer_int = Integer.parseInt(user_answer_y);

    int correct_answer_y = (int) m_value * (int) x_value + (int) b_value;

    if (user_answer_int == correct_answer_y) {
      System.out.println("You are correct!");
      return true;
    } else {
      System.out.print("Sorry, that is incorrect. ");
      System.out.println("The answer is " + correct_answer_y);
      return false;

    }
  }
  static int generate_random(double max_value, double min_value) {

    return (int) ((int) (Math.random() * ((max_value - min_value)+ 1)) + min_value);
  }
```

Comment: @KeynnerBlas i would refactor the above code to make it better. This is just the in general you would do it. 
I would definitely rework to make it more readable and better looking :)

Comment: i changed it ... i just tested this out.. works fine :)

Comment: You are right! it works in that website, its weird cause I have the same code in intelliJ and its not working, Im double checking, thank you tho for dedicating time to help me :D